# linking Microsoft.Speech with xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, speech-recognition

I'm trying to link a microphone in a mobile phone which uses android and trying to achieve voice recognition and tts. I want to use Microsot.Speech library, the thing is that how can I access the microphone.
please have a look at this sample code from microsoft's website:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Speech.Recognition;

namespace SpeechRecognitionApp
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      // Create a SpeechRecognitionEngine object for the default recognizer in the en-US locale.
      using (
      SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer =
        new SpeechRecognitionEngine(
          new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")))
      {

        // Create a grammar for finding services in different cities.
        Choices services = new Choices(new string[] { "restaurants", "hotels", "gas stations" });
        Choices cities = new Choices(new string[] { "Seattle", "Boston", "Dallas" });

        GrammarBuilder findServices = new GrammarBuilder("Find");
        findServices.Append(services);
        findServices.Append("near");
        findServices.Append(cities);

        // Create a Grammar object from the GrammarBuilder and load it to the recognizer.
        Grammar servicesGrammar = new Grammar(findServices);
        recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync(servicesGrammar);

        // Add a handler for the speech recognized event.
        recognizer.SpeechRecognized +=
          new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recognizer_SpeechRecognized);

        // Configure the input to the speech recognizer.
        recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        // Start asynchronous, continuous speech recognition.
        recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

        // Keep the console window open.
        while (true)
        {
          Console.ReadLine();
        }
      }
    }

    // Handle the SpeechRecognized event.
    static void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Recognized text: " + e.Result.Text);
    }}}
```

I think that the line of interest here is:

```
recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
```

how can I change input to be device microphone?
many thanks.

note: I copied the code above from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: You can't use any arbitrary .NET dll with Xamarin.  And Android has native TTS and speech-recognition capability.  See http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/speech/

Comment: Microsoft.Speech uses Windows only native APIs under the hood so it won't work on Android.

Comment: thanks guys.
Jason: Android doesn't support Arabic tts :(
@LexLi : are you sure? can't I convert recorded audio to .wav for example and save it in the system then process it?

Comment: On Windows, .NET passes the data down to Windows OS to process. That's how Microsoft.Speech works. Converting the audio to any format won't help you solve the processing part on Android. More info can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Speech_API